# How to merge splitted FlowFiles with the data from Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-nifi, elasticsearch-5

I have the problem with merging splitted FlowFiles. let me explain the problem step by step.

This is my sequence of processors.

[image]

In Elasticsearch I have this index and mapping:

```
PUT /myindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "myentries": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      }, 
      "properties": {
          "yid": {"type": "keyword"},
          "days": { 
              "properties": {
                        "Type1":  { "type": "date" },
                        "Type2":  { "type": "date" }
              }
            },
            "directions": { 
              "properties": {
                      "name": {"type": "keyword"},
                      "recorder":  { "type": "keyword" },
                      "direction":  { "type": "integer" }
              }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I get `directions` from Elasticsearch using `QueryElasticsearchHTTP` and then I split `directions` into using `SplitJson` in order to get 10 FlowFiles. Each FlowFile has this content: `{"name": "X","recorder": "X", "direction": "X"}`

After this, for each of 10 FlowFiles I generate the attribute `filename` using `UpdateAttribute` and `${UUID()}`. Then, I enrich each FlowFile with some constant data from ElasticSearch. In fact, the data that I merge to each FlowFile is the same. Therefore, ideally, I would like to run `Get constants from Elastic` only once instead of running it 10 times.

But anyway the key problem is different. **FlowFiles that come from `Gets constants from Elastic` have other values of `filename` and they cannot be merged with the files that come from `Set the attribute "filename"`.** I also tried to use `EvaluateJsonPath`, but had the same problem. Any idea of how to solve this problem?

**UPDATE:**

The Groovy code used in `Merge inputs...`. I am not sure if it works when in the input queues come batches of 10 and 10 files that should be merged:

```
import org.apache.nifi.processor.FlowFileFilter;
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

//get first flow file
def ff0 = session.get()
if(!ff0)return

def filename = ff0.getAttribute('filename')

//try to find files with same attribute in the incoming queue
def ffList = session.get(new FlowFileFilter(){
    public FlowFileFilterResult filter(FlowFile ff) {
        if( filename == ff.getAttribute('filename') )return FlowFileFilterResult.ACCEPT_AND_CONTINUE
        return FlowFileFilterResult.REJECT_AND_CONTINUE
    }
})

//let's assume you require two additional files in queue with the same attribute

if( !ffList || ffList.size()<1 ){
    session.rollback(false)
    return
}

//let's put all in one list to simplify later iterations
ffList.add(ff0)

//create empty map (aka json object)
def json = [:]
//iterate through files parse and merge attributes
ffList.each{ff->
    session.read(ff).withStream{rawIn->
        def fjson = new JsonSlurper().parse(rawIn)
        json.putAll(fjson)
    }
}
//create new flow file and write merged json as a content
def ffOut = session.create()
ffOut = session.write(ffOut,{rawOut->
    rawOut.withWriter("UTF-8"){writer->
        new JsonBuilder(json).writeTo(writer)
    }
} as OutputStreamCallback )
//set mime-type
ffOut = session.putAttribute(ffOut, "mime.type", "application/json")

session.remove(ffList)
session.transfer(ffOut, REL_SUCCESS)
```